# Spark application stops when reading file from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, emr

I have an application which runs on EMR and reads a csv file from s3.
However, the whole thing seems to stop (I've let it run for about an hour) when I try to read in that file from s3. Nothing happens and nothing is written to the logs any more except that the application is still running. The step in which this application is running does not fail!

I've tried copying the file to the cluster via the flag `--files` of spark-submit and reading it directly within the application with `sc.textFile(filename)`.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Have you done a thread dump on the driver to see what it is busy doing at this point?  Is this yarn client or cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I finally got back to that problem again and could "solve" it myself (I don't really know what the problem was, though...)
It seems like spark was failing to allocate worker nodes. After setting spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled to true everything is working as expected now.

Comment: I'm suspecting the application must been requesting executor containers that could not be given... Likely memory or core request too much.